# Cocoa xcode4.3 hide characters of a string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.3

I am adding string into a pickerView like this :

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", xxx, xxx];
[pickerViewObjects addObject:string];
```

what i want to do is to hide the first part of the string, or of there's something to use like charachterAtIndex it will be useful because the first part of my string has a specific number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method to get "(whitespaces) John"

```
NSString *string = @"Hello John";

    NSUInteger spacePosition = [string rangeOfString:@" "].location;

    NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init ];

    for (int i=0; i<spacePosition; i++)
        [newString appendString:@" "];

    NSString *otherPartofString = [string substringFromIndex:(spacePosition)];
    [newString appendString:otherPartofString];

    NSLog(@"new String is '%@'",newString);
    [newString release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start, count)]`, that way you will only get a new string that you can use for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

find the position of space between two strings like this:

NSUInteger spacePosition = [string rangeOfString:@" "].location

then use:

NSString *otherPartofString = [string substringFromIndex:(spacePosition+1)];

Comment: I want to hide the character before the space not to remove it, anyway thx.

Comment: you want to hide all the characters before space like this:
 
"Hello John" converted to 
"(whitespaces)  John"
or 
"XXXXX John" ?